# PowerBI Index by row combined with prevíous row

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

Hello I would need someones help please.
I want to combine two different tasks and don't know how.

First I created an row number for each group: [Description for Task1](https://radacad.com/create-row-number-for-each-group-in-power-bi-using-power-query)
I grouped the table by a station ID.

Now I want to get the value from the previous row: [Description for Task2](https://excelkingdom.blogspot.com/2019/03/how-to-get-previous-row-value-from.html)

The problem is that this doesn't work: [image: Multiple Values Error]
I think this comes due to the fakt that the index is not unique.
Because for example the index "1" exists for every ID.

Maybe it's easier to understand when u see the table. I blacked out specific values because they are not important for this.
[image: Table for Example]

I would need to only take the index+1 where the index+1 and index have the same ID.

What I want to achive is to get a column which shows me the previous value from beschreibung. But only the previuos value where the ID is the same.
[image: Example]

Does anyone know how to solve this?
My guess is that you need to do the lookupvalue task in powerquery. But I don't know how.
Maybe something like this? : [Lookup Value](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-lookup-values-in-another-table-in-the-Query-Editor/m-p/530177#M248407)

I welcome any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your update:

```
MeasurePrev = var __lastInd = CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Beschreibung]), FILTER(ALL('Table'), 'Table'[index] = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[index]) +1 ), VALUES('Table'[ID]))
return  __lastInd
```

[image]

```
CalculatedColumnPrev = var _idx = 'Table'[index] +1
var _NodeId = 'Table'[ID]
return
CALCULATE(max('Table'[Beschreibung]), FILTER(ALL('Table'),  ('Table'[index]) = _idx && 'Table'[ID] = _NodeId) )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help but this doesn't work, because the index is not unique.

Comment: Share your sample data and desired output. 

Or you can try with EARLIER (but this is not recommended to use)

https://dax.guide/earlier/

Comment: I edited my question. I hope its easier to understand now. In column beschreibung are various values, not only "Typ B". I made an example to see what the column should look like.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and am glad u know DAX so well.
But right now it is still not working. it always shows the same value for Beschreibung now.

Comment: I have add an image and i don't have this issue. 
Are you sure that, you use a full statement?

Comment: I edited my Question so u can see what my DAX looks like and what the result is.
I can't find my issue. 
But I don't understand why your code works but mine doesnt.

Comment: Ok, i have update my answer one more time. Based of what you really need, you can use Measure (first statement), or calculatedColumn (second one). CalculatedColumn are only calculated when you first define them and during a dataset refresh and physical stored in your model. Measures is calculated dynamically.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it a lot. This Solution seems to work.